# Why is iPerf UDP bandwidth so much lower that iPerf TCP?

Tags: windows-7, networking, bandwidth, iperf

I need to perform a single direction iPerf test.
Bi-directionally, using TCP, I get 25Mbps.
But single direction using UDP I only get 0.7Mbps.

Why is UDP rate so much lower that TCP?

iPerf client setting:
bin/iperf3.exe -c 10.31.186.128 -u -P 1 -i 1 -p 5201 -f m -b 2.0M -t 10

iPerf server is iPad mini running iOS7 Access Agility WIFIPERF app.
iPerf client is on DELL PRECISION M4800 Windows 7 64-bit running Iperf3 Cygwin (Jperf 2.0.2)

When I set iPerf client from 1 "Parallel Streams" to 59 streams, I get 50Mbps.

iperf3.exe -c 10.31.186.128 -u -P 59 -i 1 -p 5201 -f m -b 100.0M -t 10 Connecting to host 10.31.186.128, port 5201

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing if you have the same problem with IPerf 2.x. IPerf 3 was a rewrite that a lot of networking people don't have any faith in yet.

Comment: Did you try with iperf 2? Also I'm not seeing the actual output here. ;)